# Combinatorics: 7 character passwords

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently reviewing probability using *Probability, Statistics, and Stochastic Processes* by Peter Olofsson, and I have a dispute over the answer to problem #16 on page 67.

The question is as follows:

*"You are asked to select a password for a Web site. It must consist of five lowercase letters and two digits in any order. How many possible such passwords are there if **(a)** repetitions are allowed, **(b)** repetitions are not allowed."*

My reasoning and answer for the following question are as follows:

Since there must be $5$ lower case characters and $2$ digits the password is $7$ characters long:

X-X-X-X-X-X-X

For part **(a)** repetitions are allowed. Therefore there are $26^5$ lowercase characters that we can pick,  $10^2$ digits that we may pic. Now because The digits can be placed in any order we may pick the positions of the lowercase characters or the digits. The $5$ lowercase characters may be placed in $5$ of the $7$ slots $7C5 = 21$ ways. We don't need to do the calculation for the digits into the two remaining slots because they will automatically fall into the two remaining places.

Meaning that there are $21 * 26^5 * 10^2 = 2.5 * 10^{10}$ passwords possible.

For **(b)** repetitions are not allowed. Therefore there are $26P5$ selection of lowercase characters, and $10*9$ possible digits possible. The way we pick our possible positions are still the same $7C5 = 21 ways$.

Meaning there are $21 * 26P5 * 10 * 9 = 1.49 * 10^{10}$.

According to the back of the book: The answer

For part (a) is $26^5 * 10^2 = 1.2 * 10^9$.
For part (b) is $26P5 * 10P2 = 7.1 * 10^8$.

Notice that their answer is much smaller than mine because they do not multiply by a binomial coefficient.

Either I am over-counting or they are under-counting.

Since the numbers can be placed in any order why is it that the positions have to be counted. Can anyone give me a good argument for or against my reasoning?

Comment: I think you are correct.  And since the book's answers and yours differ by a factor of about 21, it seems to indicate that they did in fact omit the factor C(7,2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right! In fact, the author's website already acknowledges the problem: http://www.peterolofsson.com/Corrections.html

> page 67, Problem 16: replace "any order" by "that order"

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only for assuring me but for looking giving me the website to look up any corrections in the text. You have no idea how much I appreciate your assistance. :D

Comment: No prob, glad I could help! :)