# Password Problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So I have looked through many of the password problems and I haven't seen any that really answer my problem. I have a question that needs to meet a bunch of criteria (6-8 characters, contains at least one lowercase, etc.). My current issue is that the password needs exactly 1 number and 3 specials characters. How do I figure out how many different ways I can arrange them in 6, 7, and 8 character passwords? Thanks!

Comment: You could work through [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449095/combinatorics-7-character-passwords?rq=1) and apply it to your context.

Comment: You may want to elaborate as what are special characters in your case.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer your question.  Please state the exact question, then explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.